# A hard integral identity on MathSE

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration

The [following identity on MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464769/how-to-prove-int-01-tan-1-left-frac-tanh-1x-tan-1x-pi-tanh-1)

$$\int_0^{1}\arctan\left(\frac{\mathrm{arctanh}\ x-\arctan{x}}{\pi+\mathrm{arctanh}\ x-\arctan{x}}\right)\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{\pi}{8}\log\frac{\pi^2}{8}$$

seems to be very difficult to prove.

**Question:** I worked on this identity for several days without any success. Is there any clue how to prove this integral identity?

Comment: I'm waiting for Noam Elkies's solution :-)

Comment: @RonGordon Did you try this one ?

Comment: A related problem can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521993/integral-int-1-infty-frac-operatornamearccot-left1-frac2-pi-operatorn).

Comment: @Lucian: They are essentially the same problem.

Comment: I know, which is why I thought I'd use the occasion to put things a bit into perspective.

Comment: What happens if $\pi$ in the integral is replaced by some other real number? Can one give a closed-form formula for the integral in this case?

Comment: Where does this problem come from and why do you care about it?

Comment: @LevBorisov: This identity is a long-lasting problem(which was raised by another user) on  Math.SE, and I think it is just the type of identity which may appear in Ramanujan's notebooks. Although I don't know what this identity may related to, it would be better to draw more attention to this elegent identity.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

I have proved this equality by means of Cauchy’s Theorem
applied to an adequate function. Since my solution is too long to post it
here, I posted it in arXiv:

- Juan Arias de Reyna, *Computation of a Definite Integral*, arXiv:[1402.3830](http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.3830).

The function
$$G(z)=\frac{\log(1+(1+i)\,f(z)\,)}z$$
where
$$f(x)=\frac{\operatorname{arctanh}(x)-\arctan(x)}{\pi}$$
extended analytically.

Comment: That's great.  I suggest that you at least copy the definitions of the key functions $f(z)$ and $G(z)$ into your answer.

Comment: @larry, I would like to know how this question was generated.
I have seen so much structure in your integrand that I will be surprised if there is not something hidden.

Comment: Nice observation! Thanks for your answer to this identity!

Comment: Awesome answer! --- it's more than just an observation, I'd say :-)